# Export ADX Kusto time series

Tags: azure-data-explorer

When exporting, for instance to Power BI, Azure Data Explorer time series, I receive an strange structure. What's the best practice to export these data? (For example, exporting a time series prediction).

Adding details:

This is my time series chart:
[image]
And this is the time series in table format:
[image]
This table format is exactly what I get when importing from Power BI (from Kusto Explorer -> Share -> Power BI):
[image]

Comment: it might be useful if you could further explain/demonstrate what you mean by "strange structure", and how you're running the export (without those, i can only *speculate* you have a `dynamic` column in your output, which you could apply the `mv-expand` operator on)

Comment: Sorry... Additional information added

Comment: Does using `mv-expand` on the result `dynamic` columns, as previously suggested, help?

Comment: Thank you Yoni. mv-expand solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Yoni L said, using mv-expand solved the issue:
[image]